# Disable child dropdown if parent dropdown has no children

Tags: kendo-ui, cascadingdropdown

Let's assume that I have a simple, cascading Kendo UI dropdownlist for filtering products. The first ("parent") dropdown list shows all the product categories. The second ("child") dropdown list shows all the product subcategories under the selected parent category. **However, some of the categories do not have subcategories.**

When a category does not have any subcategories, the subcategory dropdown should remain disabled. Unfortunately, the default behavior of the widget is that the subcategory dropdown is enabled as long as a category is selected, regardless of the existence of subcategories.

Does anyone have any suggestions for disabling a child dropdown when the parent doesn't have any children?